# Did kingoroot install bloatware on my phone? Or is this a legitimate android locksreen?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, rooting, lock-screens, bloatware

Long story short, I have rooted my phone in order to resolve 'low on internal storage' issues (turned out the cache folder grew to almost 2GB). I have used [kingoroot](http://www.kingoapp.com/) as suggested in [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/1185/101383) and it worked nicely.

However, shortly after the rooting, I noticed I had a new lockscreen I've never seen before:

[image]

Before the rooting I had what I believe is the official Android lockscreen, where you slide your finger from the center of the screen to a lock icon, camera, or unread messages if you have any.

I certainly don't remember installing a lockscreen app, but after rooting and cleaning the internal storage I finally was able to install updates in Google Play, and there were quite a few of these.

How can I find out where did this lockscreen came from? Is this how Android lockscreen looks now on Android 4.4.2? If not, is it expected to get unwanted software when I root my phone? And finally, how do I uninstall it?

Edit: the [method](http://www.w0lfdroid.com/2015/05/How-to-Remove-Replace-KingUser-KingRoot-with-SuperSU.html) for replacing KingoRoot with SuperSU didn't work. I've got [error messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PyCLj.png) about non-existing files, and SuperSU started but couldn't update the binary.

Comment: This is certainly bloatware - some [possible culprits here](https://www.reddit.com/r/galaxynote5/comments/3s3s7l/fast_charging_lock_screen_is_obnoxious_any_way_to/)

Comment: also see this answer http://android.stackexchange.com/a/145358/131553 and this [comment](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/171450/how-do-i-stop-android-to-auto-enabling-allow-unknown-sources#comment219474_171450)

Comment: @beeshyams Thanks, this case certainly looks similar to mine. The problem is, I don't see a "DU quick charge" (actually, anything suspicious at all) in my apps list.

Comment: Run the apps mentioned in the linked comment  above ( Toaster and Notification history apps) and see if you can track the app

Comment: I was able to do a simple uninstall of kingoroot Superuser using the Apps tool, and then install Super SU using the play store.  Root was preserved.